# File Upload Error in MediaWiki 1.22.3 - Could not create directory "mwstore://local-backend/local-public/7/70"

Tags: ubuntu, upload, mediawiki

We recently upgraded our MediaWiki installation to 1.22.3 running on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. Now when we try to upload files, we get the following error:

Could not create directory "mwstore://local-backend/local-public/7/70"

Comment: I had the same problem with my own installation. I use ver 1.22.2, and every thing worked fine until yesterday I couldn't upload an image. The solution was to add the 'write' permission to 'images' directory. Somehow this permission was removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found the solution in the MediaWiki documentation. The problem was the ownership of the images directory. Making the adjustments suggested in the documentation eliminated the problem. See the following for details:  http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuring_file_uploads

Specifically, do this:

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data images/
sudo chmod -R 755 images/`

Your installation MIGHT use the uploads/ directory instead. If so, do the same to it.

Comment: Thanks, You need to check what user your webserver is using then chown images to that user. Love to have an install script that handles this

Comment: This fixed it for me in 2022.  Not sure how it ended up getting change in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a **Windows Server**.
The cause was that the **user** that was running the wiki **app-pool** (IUSR) did not have acceess rights to the **mediawiki\images** folder.

Granting additional read/write access to the images folder solved the problem.

Hope this helps anyone encountering the same issue.