# Error uploading images with mediawiki (on Directadmin)

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, mediawiki

I've installed mediawiki on my webserver (with directadmin), but I'm having trouble enabling the uploading of images (a .jpg in this case)

I've set `$wgEnableUploads = true;` in the settings and checked that the `images` folder is writeable (it's set to 755). But when I try to upload a test image called `testimage.jpg` I get the error:

```
Could not store file "/tmp/phpjNV3oh" at "mwstore://local-backend/local-public/1/13/testimage.jpg".
```

Since I'm on shared webhosting and only have acces to the directadmin interface I can't set the owner of the images folder (which is an answer [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread%3aProject%3aSupport_desk/Trouble_uploading_after_installation)). I've tried setting the folder to 777, and that doesn't change anything either.

Does anyone know what the problem is? Could it be that I'm using cloudflare? Also, why is the url returned in the error (`mwstore://local-backend/local-public/1/13/testimage.jpg"`) not a normal url (like `mysite.com/wiki/images` or something)?

Comment: You need to look into the error log (and perhaps raise the logging level), the *"`mwstore://`"* at the beginning of the path denotes a stream-wrapper which is a subcomponent used by media-wiki. Unless that sub-component does provide more information (either via logs or otherwise), all you know is that a file could not be stored. There can be millions of reasons, so I would not guess with the file-rights longer than a minute. Instead start to troubleshoot that now. Here is also a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22303606/367456 - maybe it helps.

Comment: @hakre, I've checked around a little, and the image has been succesfully uploaded to the `images/temp/d/d2` directory. But when I try to access the image directly in my browser, I get a 403 error. So it's probably that mediawiki can't access the `images/temp/d/d2` folder, just as I can't. Problem is, how do I tell apache not to block any access? Can I put a httpd.conf in the parent with the settings suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server?

Comment: Sounds more like that perhaps mediawiki wanted to change the access rights of that file but didn't manage to do that. If you have problems to chmod 777 I doubt you can actually change apache conf. You might have more luck with .htaccess with your hoster. In any case I would trouble-shoot that with the server admin. And I personally would remote debug the code with a step debugger to find the exact cause of the problem quickly.

Comment: @hakre: This is from the error log: `[Sun Jun 08 23:20:46.420476 2014] [:error] [pid 6199] [client example.com:23278] PHP Warning:  popen() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/username/domains/example.com/public_html/wiki/includes/filebackend/FSFileBackend.php on line 702, referer: http://www.example.com/wiki/index.php?title=Special:Upload&wpDestFile=testimage.jpg&wpForReUpload=1`

Comment: @hakre: And `[Sun Jun 08 23:16:22.684117 2014] [:error] [pid 6196] [client example.com:39879] PHP Warning:  cp '/tmp/phplnL46o' '/home/username/domains/example.com/public_html/wiki/images/1/13/testimage.jpg'\n in /home/username/domains/example.com/public_html/wiki/includes/filebackend/FSFileBackend.php on line 282, referer: http://www.example.com/wiki/Special:Upload`

Comment: @hakre, last unique error: `[Sun Jun 08 23:16:22.684085 2014] [:error] [pid 6196] [client example.com:39879] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/username/domains/example.com/public_html/wiki/includes/filebackend/FSFileBackend.php on line 710, referer: http://www.example.com/wiki/Special:Upload`

Comment: @hakre, also, I don't have problems chmodding to 777. That I can do. However, I don't have commandline access to the site, only through ftp and directadmin..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem twice on shared hosts, and there were two solutions for me.

One:

- Set `$wgHashedUploadDirectory = false` on `LocalSettings.php`, then try to upload another file.

Doing this all your files will be uploaded to `$wgUploadDirectory, /images/foo.jpg` instead of `/images/x/xx/foo.jpg`

Please note that if you change this now, you should not set it to `true` in the future, else you will need to manually move your files into the hashed directory structure.

Two:

- Contact your host's support service

When i emailed the situation to my host's support service, they replied that all folders inside `/my_wiki/images` were owned by root instead of apache-user, and since i couldn't `chown` they did it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the proper security context type so that SELinux stops complaining.

```
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t /var/www/mediawiki123/images/
```

Don't forget to set the directory back to the correct permissions.

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/mediawiki123/images/
```

For all of your SELinux needs, browse through [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/SELinux#Uploading_Images).